# Page_load() is firing on checkbox selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

Whenever i am trying to select the checkbox of treeview, the page is reloaded and the checkbox is again deselected.
How can i get rid from this problem.
Thanks in advance!
.cs page

```
protected void RadTreeView1_NodeCheck(object o, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

.aspx page

Comment: would you like to show your code?

Comment: make `autopostback = false`...

Comment: set AutoPostBack="false" .

Comment: try binding the tree on the OnInit event, if the checkboxes need to postback

Comment: <telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server" OnNodeCheck="RadTreeView1_NodeCheck" CheckBoxes="True">
                                 </telerik:RadTreeView>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to set AutoPostBack to false

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1"   
    runat="server"   
    AutoPostBack="false"   
    Text="Checkbox control" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest suggestion is just set autopostback= false but I assume you need that as you want to do something when selecting checkbox but don't want to have whole reload. 
I think it might happen because you forgot to add

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
//your code
}
```

inside your page_load function.

Answer (score 0):

set AutoPostBack="false" in asp:CheckBox tag.